# Why isn't Recaptcha showing up from PHP using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, captcha

**::EXPLINATION::**

In an HTML file, I'm attempting to load a registration frame with a captcha check. The form itself shows up. The captcha does not. So I know that the javascript (posted below) gets what I want it to get. But there's something wrong that is keeping my captcha from showing up.

Just as a final note, I'm targetting a div with the id "splashTarget" I use CSS to arrange everything how I want it. I'm not going to post that because its probably not relevant, but if you think I do need to post it to get help let me know.

**::CODE::**

The form that doesn't seem to work:

```
<div class="splash"> </div>
<div style="text-align:left" id="registrationSplash" class="splashContent">
    <div style="text-align:right">
        <a style="color:darkred" href="javascript:closeSplash()">[ CANCEL ]</a>
    </div>
    <h1>REGISTER</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="registerForm">
                <?PHP
                require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                $publickey = "[censored]";                  
                echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
                echo '<!--'.recaptcha_get_html($publickey).'-->';
                ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="60"></td>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="60"></td>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>E-mail Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="60"></td>
                <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan=4 style="text-align:right">

                <button onclick="submitFormRegisterSplash()" type="button" name="submit" value="Login">Register!</button>
                </th>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </form>

    <div id="status" />
</div>
```

The actual call to recaptia.

```
                <?PHP
                require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                $publickey = "[censored]";
                echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
                echo '<!--'.recaptcha_get_html($publickey).'-->';
                ?>
```

Javascript Function used to load Register form:

```
function onRegisterClicked() {
    var onRegisterClickedHttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        onRegisterClickedHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        onRegisterClickedHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(onRegisterClickedHttp.readyState==4 && onRegisterClickedHttp.status==200) {
                var response = onRegisterClickedHttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("splashTarget").innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    }

    onRegisterClickedHttp.open("GET", "Verification/RegisterSplash.php", true);
    onRegisterClickedHttp.send();
}
```

Result on Webpage after calls to create

```
<div id="splashTarget">

<div class="splash"> </div>
<div style="text-align:left" id="registrationSplash" class="splashContent">
    <div style="text-align:right">
        <a style="color:darkred" href="javascript:closeSplash()">[ CANCEL ]</a>
    </div>
    <h1>REGISTER</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="registerForm">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LehEsgSAAAAAAH2xfKSXKSdldMwoiOqZyO5TupV"></script>

    <noscript>
        &lt;iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LehEsgSAAAAAAH2xfKSXKSdldMwoiOqZyO5TupV" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;
        &lt;input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/&gt;
    </noscript><!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LehEsgSAAAAAAH2xfKSXKSdldMwoiOqZyO5TupV"></script>

    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LehEsgSAAAAAAH2xfKSXKSdldMwoiOqZyO5TupV" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>-->      <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="60"></td>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="60"></td>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>E-mail Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="60"></td>
                <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">

                <button onclick="submitFormRegisterSplash()" type="button" name="submit" value="Login">Register!</button>
                </th>
            </tr> 
        </tbody></table>
    </form>

    <div id="status">
</div>

</div></div>
```

The Website in action is gumonshoe dot net slash Registration
You'll need to choose to try to register to see the pop up. I disabled the CSS that created the splash screen thinking that it might have been an issue with z-indexes. That doesn't appear to be the case.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form HTML DOES work (see http://jsfiddle.net/5p5K3/). The error is caused by a feature:

`<script>` tags which are injected using `.innerHTML = ...`. `<script>` are not parsed (functions and variables inside these tags are not defined, nor called). You have to include the CAPTCHA code inside the page, instead of adding it using AJAX.

### EDIT

Add this HTML code (inside the `<head>` block):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Overwrite your function by my suggestion (replace `<PUBLIC kEY HERE>` by your public key):

```
function onRegisterClicked() {
    Recaptcha.create("<PUBLIC KEY HERE>", "splashTarget", {
        theme: "red",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there another function which does parse what's given? Maybe by calling eval or something similar?

Comment: See my updated answer. If your question has been answered, use "Accept answer", so that other visitors (from Google, for instance) know that this answer is correct.

Comment: To do what I wanted I did the following: (1) Added a <div id="captchaTarget"> to my form. (2) Did the above as Rob W suggested, changing splashTarget to captchaTarget, but inside my Ajax request. (3) Removed script code from other location. -- Thanks much for leading me to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious problem: The inserted recaptcha code is commented out with `<!-- -->`. Commented-out html/js is NOT going to be rendered/executed. Change

```
echo '<!--'.recaptcha_get_html($publickey).'-->';
```

to

```
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

Comment: I echo'd it twice because I wanted to have in a comment exactly what was coming out:

    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    echo '<!--'.recaptcha_get_html($publickey).'-->';

:: So, sorry, but that's not the answer. Wish it was though. :(